# Get notified once a net.Socket is in the CLOSED state

Tags: node.js, sockets, https, tcp

I wrote a simple `HTTPS` server written in NodeJS (v10.19):

```
const https = require('https');
const options = {key: ..., cert:...};

server = https.createServer(options, (req, res) => {
   ...
   res.end("Hello!\n");
});

server.on('connection', socket => {
   socket.on('close', () => {
      console.log("Close event fired\n");
   });
});

server.listen(5555);
```

I'm looking for a way to determine when a connection with a client is over.
By "over", I mean both sides of the socket are in the `CLOSED` state (both FIN packets, and the last ACK packet, have all been sent on the socket).

I went through all relevant NodeJS docs (`HTTPS`, `net.Socket`, `stream.Duplex`) and couldn't find a proper solution.

My questions are:

1. What is the exact definition of a "fully closed" socket the docs are referring to?
2. Is there a way to achieve what I want?

What I tried was listen on the `net.Socket`'s `close` event, since the docs state it's

> Emitted once the socket is fully closed.

In reality, the event is fired as soon as my server sends its FIN packet to the client, and before the client's FIN packet, and the server's last ACK.

What I observe:

```
* Server FIN *
== 'close' event fired ==
* Client FIN *
* Server ACK *
```

What I want:

```
* Server FIN *
* Client FIN *
* Server ACK *
== get notified somehow ==
```